# AWS Amplify, custom domain not working, DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I can't seem to get custom domain to work.
When I used the amplifyapp.com url, the app is fully deployed and functional.
Dispite the Domain management have the custom domain in available status, and the hosting envoriment UI has the custom URL as the deployed link. When I open the URL I get the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. Any pointer?

I went through all the troubleshooting docs, and watched a couple how other people went through the setup process. The process itself is pretty simple so not much to look for there. And I did also checked with [www.whatsmydns.net](http://www.whatsmydns.net) and it is propergated fully.

Comment: For whomever running into the same issue, this post fixed it for me! (Removing redirect)
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3562